# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Using old ASP.NET 2.0 database structure for authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

So I've been developing an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application for a while now and I was wondering if it's possible to use an older SQL database with the following tables in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 application.

[image: Database tables]

As I [read online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478948.aspx) this is the default database structure for using ASP.NET 2.0 SqlMemebershipProvider classes. Is it possible to implement this into my application and if so, how should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure you talk about is called ASP.NET Membership and it works for any ASP.NET version, up to 4.5.
There's no built-in way to run Membership in ASP.NET Core because Membership has been dead for many years. You have two paths to follow:

1. Move to ASP.NET Identity, works for both ASP.NET 4.x and Core. You will need to migrate your data manually.
2. Create the classes to consume the data manually. Notice that you won't have any of the security features of Membership so I strongly discourage this.

Of course, a 3rd path would be to keep using the outdated Membership on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

Comment: What do you mean by "create the classes to consume the data manually"? To create a class which uses the same properties as the membership classes?

Comment: @Jeroen Yeah, you'd need to use either ADO.NET or some ORM to consume the data from the tables

Comment: So for example in my Startup.cs I could use the services.AddIdentity<CustomUser, CustomRole>() method and the user and the role would be those classes?

Comment: @Jeroen That could work, but you would likely need to implement custom classes, for example for `IPasswordHasher` (what Membership used is extremely old, the default implementation for Identity is much stronger)

Comment: We moved to ASP.NET identity

Answer (score 0):

The old table structure is not compatible with ASP.NET Identity. Plain and simple. Your best path forward is to generate the tables that Identity *does* use, and then migrate the data from the old tables to those. Nothing else will work.